# How to match start of line white space only when a specific word is after

Tags: regex

I want to match white space at the beginning of the line but only the the next word is PATCH, PUT, POST or GET

```
    edit_user_registration GET     /users/edit(.:format)      registrations#edit
                           PATCH   /users(.:format)           registrations#update
```

In the case above only the second line white space. I tried this:

```
(^\s*)+(POST|GET|DELETE|PUT|PATCH|OPTIONS)
```

Problem is this will match even the "PATCH" word but want to match only the whitespace before "PATCH".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lookahead instead:

```
^\s*(?=(?:POST|GET|DELETE|PUT|PATCH|OPTIONS)\b)
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jN6hC8/2)

The last `\b` makes the pattern match the words only as whole words. If it is not what you need, you can remove it.

A positive lookahead just checks if a pattern matches the text and returns true or false, either fail or pass, without consuming the characters.

Also, `(\s*)+` (*one or more zero or more whitespace symbols*) can be shortened to just `\s*` (*0+ whitespace symbols*).

Comment: @Tushar: I believe it is not that necessary in this scenario, but I always prefer to play it safe.

Comment: Works with \b or without it.

Comment: Shouldn't the `\b` be inside the lookahead?

Comment: @SebastianProske: Yeah, what a typo - I must be rather tired now.

Comment: You might also consider using a possesive modifier or an atomic group for the `\s*`, to avoid unnecessary backtracking if there is no match. Not sure which regex flavour OP is using, so they might not be supported.

Comment: Yes. The fact we do not know the regex flavor is always disturbing. Surely a possessive quantifier would be great to use here `^\s*+(?=(?:POST|GET|DELETE|PUT|PATCH|OPTIONS)\b)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
^\s*(?=POST|GET|DELETE|PUT|PATCH|OPTIONS)
```

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/yS6tX5/2).

This regex will match the empty string on lines that start by the matched verb. If you don't want this behaviour, change the `*` to `+` :

```
^\s+(?=POST|GET|DELETE|PUT|PATCH|OPTIONS)
```